# How can I test if an input char is between 1-9?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I'm writing a program in 8086 assembly language that asks for a single digit that is between 1-9 and then stores it. If it is not between 1-9, it's supposed to loop back.

What would be a good way to test it and make it loop back (and allow you to input another digit) until it meets the requirements?

My code so far:

```
section .data
  prompt1 db "Enter a single digit  digit between 1-9 --> $"
section .text   
  ;Display prompt
  mov   ah,9        ; print prompt
  mov   dx,prompt1  ; load register with prompt1
  int   21h         ; display it
  ; Input character and store.
  mov   ah,1        ; reach char fcn
  int   21h         ; read character into al
  mov   bl,al       ; store character into bl
```

Comment: What part is causing you problem? Do you know about comparisons, conditional branches and ascii code?

Comment: I know about condition branches, but not  familiar with comparisons.

Comment: Then read the reference page about `cmp`. TL;DR: you can just do something like `cmp bl, '1'` and then use the conditional branches that you already know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/x86/5808/control-flow#t=201702260707522818253

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested it, but in general, the code should check if `BL` is less than 31h or greater than 39h. These are the ASCII values of `1` and `9`.

So some example code could look like this:

```
  ; Input character and store.
loop1:              ; added label
  mov   ah,1        ; read char fcn
  int   21h         ; read character into AL
  mov   bl, al      ; store character into BL
  ; now comes the additional code
  cmp   bl, 31h     ; compare BL to the ASCII value of '1'
  jb    loop1       ; jump back if ASCII value is less than '1' = 31h
  cmp   bl, 39h     ; compare BL to the ASCII value of '9'
  ja    loop1       ; jump back if ASCII value is greater than '9' = 39h
  ; BL contains an ASCII value between '1' and '9' which integer value can be acquired by subtracting the value 30h
```

Comment: `jl` is signed, `ja` unsigned. This will work, because you don't need values above 127 from input to work, but it looks like bug upon reading the source, so it would annoy me a lot, as I would have to think about how it works every time. `jb` is unsigned "below".

Comment: By moving `AL` to `BL` only **after** both compares (using `AL`), you would have obtained a free code size optimization.

Comment: @Ped7g: Thanks. Of course you're right. I fixed my error.

Comment: @SepRoland: Of course you're right, too. But my aim was to change as little as possible of the code of the question.